# AppCompat Button Without Elevation

Tags: android, android-button, android-appcompat, android-elevation

I have a few dozen buttons in my app and a style that inherits from `Widget.AppCompat.Button`. Most of the buttons have an elevation and state change animation. Awesome.

What isn't awesome is that a few of the buttons don't have anything of that extra goodness.

Here's an example of one of the working buttons

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/defaultPadding"
    android:minHeight="?attr/minTouchSize"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListRowLabel" />
```

Here's a snippet from where the buttons do NOT work

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="?attr/minTouchSize" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="?attr/minTouchSize" />
</LinearLayout>
```

These are on separate layouts. Things I've tried:

- I've added `button1` to be in the same layout file as the button bar and `button1` still works.
- If I remove the weights from one of the buttons in the bar they don't work.
- I've tried explicitly putting my button style on each button
- If I make the button bar a vertical layout **and** make the buttons match parent then it works! But that isn't what I want.

I want to make these buttons have state animation and elevation while in a horizontal layout. Aka I want the buttons to take up equal space and sit next two each other. How can I achieve this?

I'm using appcompat 22.2.1

Comment: Did you try to put style explicitly on each button?

Comment: @Androider unfortunately no dice :/

Comment: I've tried remove minHeight attrs and put your code into a main layout of an activity and it works well. Maybe have problem with these params.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is in your activity Theme !!!!

its good to mention that the buttons takes their style from Activity THEME.
what you can do is this:

1. define a style :

   ```
   <style name="ThemeMaterialButtonColor" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
   <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/md_teal_500</item></style>
   ```
2. Then in your button in your xml add this :

   app:theme="@style/ThemeMaterialButtonColor"